# How to build indexes / optimize for this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a table in my database that looks something like this.

```
Id (Int), Name(NVarChar), DateCreated(DateTime), Message(NVarChar)
```

Only 3 queries are run against this database table

```
select top 1 * 
from table1 
where Name = @input   // almost all Names are unique, used 55% of the time

select top 100 
from table1   
where DateCreated > @input    // used 40% of the time

insert...    //create new record, used 5% of the time
```

This table has over 20 million rows.

How can I optimize this database?

Answer (score 1):

Add an index on Name and on DateCreated

Comment: How do I do that? Im new to database design

Comment: Never worked with sql server 2008, but this should do it: CREATE  INDEX name_index on table1 (Name); CREATE  INDEX date_index on table1 (DateCreated);  Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx